# How can I use List view.builder and item builder with a select range?

Tags: flutter, dart

Lets say I have a list of numbers from one to ten. How can I use list view builder/ item builder to, say, only print 2-7 or 7-9 instead of the entire list?

Comment: basically how can i specify a range?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the core library provided by dart to handle value generation for List as follow:

```
  var listNumber = new List<int>.generate(10, (i) => i + 1);
```

And then loop through your list in ListView.builder or just use ListView since you haven't a huge list ,

```
ListView.builder(
                itemCount: listNumber.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, i) => Text(listNumber[i]),
              ),
```

with some improvement, the whole working app would be :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  var listNumber = new List<int>.generate(10, (i) => i + 1);
  var startItem = 2;
  var endItem = 7;
  bool all = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Printing number',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Printing number'),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical: 15.0,
            horizontal: 10.0,
          ),
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: all ? listNumber.length : (endItem - startItem) + 1,
            itemBuilder: (_, i) => PrintRange(i,all,listNumber,startItem),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PrintRange extends StatelessWidget {
  final int i;
  final bool all;
  final List listNumber;
  final int startItem;

  PrintRange(this.i,this.all,this.listNumber,this.startItem);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 5.0,
      child: ListTile(
        title: Center(
          child: Text(
            all ? listNumber[i].toString() : listNumber[i + startItem].toString(),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As a bonus, you can use the Slider class to improve it : [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html)

Comment: Please accept , and upvote the answer if you find it correct and helpful .

Answer (score 0):

List views build its items one by one. if you assigned a key to each item and then before returning the you can try returning a empty widget if that key is met.

put your range into a List and check if the item, the list view returns has that property

```
List range = [];
```

modify the List view,

```
ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index){
  if (range.contains('Your Key')){
     return Container();
  } else {
     return Your Normal List Item;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving a useless container widget, you should use itemBuilder and simple maths.
Taking your example suppose We have a list of numbers:

```
List<int> numbers = [0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

Now we can have start and end index for which you want the list to be shown

```
int startIndex = 2;
int endIndex = 7;
```

So now using simple maths you could achieve what you want. Just see the code below, it works like a charm and is more efficient rather than provide a widget which would be no use:

```
int itemCount = (endIndex - startIndex)+1;
```

now use this in your listview as:

```
ListView.builder(
              itemCount: itemCount,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return (Text(numbers[startIndex + index].toString()));
              })
```

So the whole working code would be:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<int> numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    int startIndex = 2;
    int endIndex = 6;
    int itemCount = (endIndex - startIndex) + 1;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 300,
          width: 100,
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: itemCount,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return (Text(numbers[startIndex + index].toString()));
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

So you can customize the way you want your listview builder to work